# Is there an API to get PlayStore star rating?

Tags: android, api, google-play

I need an API to get the PlayStore rating of an app. Do you know to get this rating with an API?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no official API by google to get the application review details from Play Store. But there are many Third Part APIs which can help you get the data. You can try [AppTweek](https://www.apptweak.io/documentation/android/application_metadata).

Answer (score 4):

There are other API market place you can use.
You can search on https://rapidapi.com/.

Or you can go through the one suggested by @dante30.